# How to use oracle flash recovery option?

Tags: oracle

I an using oracle 10g and I want to use flash recovery option to recover the deleted table by accidently.How to achieve this?

Comment: A table where the data was deleted, or a table [that was dropped](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/backup.102/b14192/flashptr004.htm)? Assuming you mean it was dropped, is your recycle bin active, is your table in it, and have you tried [what the documentation shows](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/backup.102/b14192/flashptr004.htm#sthref629)?

Comment: accidentally I dropped table .Recovery for the dropped table.